# ¿Cómo posicionar tarjetas (cards) bootstrap una al lado de la otra?

Tags: html, bootstrap

Necesito hacer un diseño no muy complejo en la cual, el **ejemplo 2 y ejemplo 3** debe estar uno arriba de otro. Me explico a continuación:

card ejemplo 1: tiene un alto de 600

card ejemplo 2 y 3: tiene un alto de 300

La idea es que la tarjeta de ejemplo 1 quede sola con su dimensión de 600, mientras que la 2 y 3 que tienen dimensión de 300, queden una arriba del otro, para que complete el alto de 600, no es la idea que la tarjeta de ejemplo 3 quede debajo del todo. La siguiente imagen ilustra de manera más detallada.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A continuación muestro mi código

```html
         <div class="row">
                <div class="card col-sm-4">
                    <div class="card-header " height="600">
                        <h4 class="">Ejemplo 1</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                    <canvas  id="chart" height="600" ></canvas>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                            <div class="card col-sm-8" height="300">
                    <div class="card-header " >
                        <h4 class="">ejemplo 2</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                  <!--  <canvas  id="chart" height="300" ></canvas> -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                                
                                <div class="card col-sm-8" height="300">
                    <div class="card-header " >
                        <h4 class="">ejemplo 3</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                   <!-- <canvas  id="chart" height="300" ></canvas> -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

Cada tarjeta tendrá su gráfico correspondiente pero ese es otro tema, solo me interesa el diseño.

Comment: Indica la versión de bootstrap

Comment: No olvides además agregar en el snippet la versión de bootstrap que estás utilizando.

Answer (score 0):

vas bien, solo recuerda el esquema de la pagina web, en tu ejemplo requieres un contenedor general, y en este se dividira en 2, el 1ro contendra el div card ejemplo 1, y el 2do contenedor tendra el div card ejemplo 2, y seguido del div card ejemplo 3, te anexo la correccion junto con algun comentario para que ubiques los divs que comente , use bootstrap 5.2 pero deberia servir con otras versiones

```html
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS v5.2.1 -->
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    
    
 <div class="row">
        <!-- primer div individual -->
        <div class="card col-sm-4">
          <div class="card-header" height="600">
            <h4 class="">Ejemplo 1</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <canvas id="chart" height="600"></canvas>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- segundo div que incluyen 2 -->

        <div class="card col-sm-8" height="600">
           <!--  segundo div -->
          <div class="card col-sm-8" height="300">
            <div class="card-header">
              <h4 class="">ejemplo 2</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                  <canvas id="chart" height="300"></canvas>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- tercer div -->

          <div class="card col-sm-8" height="300">
            <div class="card-header">
              <h4 class="">ejemplo 3</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                  <canvas id="chart" height="300"></canvas>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        
            <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-7VPbUDkoPSGFnVtYi0QogXtr74QeVeeIs99Qfg5YCF+TidwNdjvaKZX19NZ/e6oz"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
```